# How does one tell if your paying a ETC or ETH address?

Tags: addresses, ethereum-classic

How can you tell if your paying an ETC or ETH address? Which wallets can check for you? It's scary if I have both eth and etc wallets and when I make a payment it deducts from both.

Answer (score 1):

Your ETH wallet, is also an ETC wallet. A transaction for the ETH chain can be replayed on the ETC chain, and vice-versa.

See here to protect yourself https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/07/26/onward_from_the_hard_fork/